# Animated SVG circles (timer and progress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

How can I change this:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
    percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = options.percent + '%';
    
if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

//imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    margin:80px;
    width:220px; height:220px;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="10"></div>
```

To get this:

[image]

outer circle is just a progress from 0 to 100% 
inner - timer

I did this 
but through the ass
http://codepen.io/di3orlive/pen/wKjBzY
I would like to do it more nicer
and with an arrow

Comment: have you tried to use a dash array for the stroke of the circle? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray If you set the stroke width to a relative large value and the gaps between the dashes too, this could do it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
  percent: el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
  size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
  lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 4,
  rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
}

function Gauge() {
  this.to_rad = to_rad = Math.PI / 180;
  this.percentBg = "#efefef";
  this.percentFg = "#555555";
  this.tickFg = "#cccccc";
  this.tickBg = "transparent";
  this.tickFill = true;
  this.tickDirection = -1; // 1=clockwise, -1=counterclockewise
  this.percent = 0;
  this.size = 220;
  this.lineWidth = 14;
  this.rotate = 0;
  this.ticks = 40;
  this.tick = 0;
  this.can = document.createElement('canvas');
  this.ctx = this.can.getContext('2d');
}


Gauge.prototype.drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent, drawArrow) {
  var ctx = this.ctx;
  var circleMargin = 10; // need room for arrowhead
  var radius = (this.size - this.lineWidth - circleMargin) / 2;

  ctx.save();
  var mid = this.size / 2;
  ctx.translate(mid, mid);
  ctx.rotate(-90 * to_rad);
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  var endRadians = 360 * percent * this.to_rad;
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, endRadians, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.filStyle = color;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();

  if (drawArrow === true && percent !== 1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rotate(endRadians);

    var arrowWidth = this.lineWidth + 12;
    var arrowHeight = 10;
    ctx.moveTo(radius - (arrowWidth / 2), 0);
    ctx.lineTo(radius + (arrowWidth / 2), 0);
    ctx.lineTo(radius, arrowHeight);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  ctx.restore();
};

Gauge.prototype.drawTicks = function() {
  var circleMargin = 10; // need room for arrowhead
  var radius = (this.size - this.lineWidth - circleMargin) / 2;
  var ctx = this.ctx;

  ctx.save();
  var mid = this.size / 2;
  ctx.translate(mid, mid);
  ctx.rotate(-90 * to_rad);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;

  var angle = 360 / this.ticks;
  var tickSize = 20;
  var tickMargin = 10;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.ticks; i++) {
    if ((i < this.tick && this.tickFill == true) || i == this.tick) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.tickFg;
    } else {
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.tickBg;
    }
    ctx.save();
    if (this.tickDirection === -1) {
      ctx.rotate((360 - (i * angle)) * this.to_rad);
    } else {
      ctx.rotate(i * angle * this.to_rad);
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(radius - tickSize - tickMargin, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(radius - tickMargin, 0);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }
  ctx.restore();
};

Gauge.prototype.render = function(el) {
  this.can.width = this.can.height = this.size;
  this.span = document.createElement('span');

  el.innerHTML = "";
  el.appendChild(this.can);
  el.appendChild(this.span);

  var self = this;
  var ctx = self.ctx;

  function loop() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    self.drawCircle(self.percentBg, self.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
    self.drawCircle(self.percentFg, self.lineWidth, self.percent / 100, true);
    self.drawTicks();
    self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      loop()
    }, 1000 / 30);
    
  }

  loop();
}

var myGauge = new Gauge();

myGauge.size = options.size;
myGauge.percent = options.percent;
myGauge.lineWidth = options.lineWidth;
myGauge.percent = options.percent;
myGauge.render(el)

var myGauge2 = new Gauge();

myGauge2.size = options.size;
myGauge2.percent = options.percent;
myGauge2.lineWidth = options.lineWidth;
myGauge2.percent = options.percent;
myGauge2.tickFg = "#FF8800";
myGauge2.tickBg = "#EEEEEE";
myGauge2.tickFill = false;
myGauge2.ticks = 60;
myGauge2.tickDirection = 1;
myGauge2.render(document.getElementById('gauge'));

var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

var countDown = 99;

function dataLoop() {


  myGauge.percent = myGauge.percent > 100 ? 100 : (myGauge.percent * 1) + .1;

  var elapsedMs = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime; // milliseconds;
  var elapsedSec = elapsedMs / 1000;
  var remainSec = Math.floor(countDown - elapsedSec);  
  var progress = remainSec <=0 ? 1 : elapsedSec / countDown;
  myGauge.tick = Math.floor(progress * myGauge.ticks); 
  myGauge.span.innerHTML = remainSec > 0 ? remainSec + " sec" : "---";
  
  var d = new Date();

  myGauge2.percent = (d.getMinutes() / 60) * 100;
  if (myGauge2.percent > 100) myGauge2.percent = 100;
  myGauge2.tick = d.getSeconds();
  myGauge2.span.innerHTML = d.getSeconds() + " sec";
  setTimeout(dataLoop,1000/30);
}

dataLoop();
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
span {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  line-height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="10"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="gauge"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wow this is awesome tnx. 
can u show how make the same functionality as in codepen example?

Comment: @ДмитрийНеважнов I tried to do a countdown based on remaining seconds.

Comment: can u look at 79line
http://jsfiddle.net/ffg58zpx/6/
cant bind tick circle and timer

Comment: I made a class for the gauge to give you an idea of how to customize.  Are you trying to display the amount of time remaining until 100 percent?

Comment: yes. 100sec no tickLine. 50sec = 50%of tickLine.  exactly like in this example http://codepen.io/di3orlive/pen/wKjBzY

Comment: @ДмитрийНеважнов I updated the code to show ((elapsed / countDown) * ticks) like in the example.  The logic for setting what tick to show is not part of the class and you can set that however you want.  As far as binding the time to your data you'll probably want to set values when you get a progress update and then render.  I have it rendering 30 frames a second which is probably overkill and you might want want to render only one frame per data update.

Comment: u the best) i 2 do what I need http://jsfiddle.net/ffg58zpx/9/
but now new challenge -> transfer everyone in angular directive.
I do not know yet,
how does canvas work with angular, but I will try to do something..

Thank you so much.
Is there anything I can do? just write me